# How to strip or replace all matches of a pattern from a string in Bash?

Tags: bash, replace, strip, dirname

I am trying to write the dirname function in Bash so that it doesn't use any external commands.

```
function dirname() {
  local path=$1
  [[ $path =~ ^[^/]+$ ]] && dir=. || {              # if path has no slashes, set dir to .
    [[ $path =~ ^/+$ ]]  && dir=/ || {              # if path has only slashes, set dir to /
      local IFS=/ dir_a i
      read -ra dir_a <<< "$path"                    # read the components of path into an array
      dir="${dir_a[0]}"
      for ((i=1; i < ${#dir_a[@]}; i++)); do        # strip out any repeating slashes
        [[ ${dir_a[i]} ]] && dir="$dir/${dir_a[i]}" # append unless it is an empty element
      done
    }
  }

  [[ $dir ]] && printf '%s\n' "$dir"                # print only if not empty
}
```

In order to remove any repeating `/` from the path, I had to use the array logic. Is there a simpler way to do the same with [Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)? I tried, but I don't seem to get it right.

Basically, I want to replace all occurrences of multiple consecutive slashes with a single slash each.

Comment: `echo "${path%\/*}"`?

Comment: That would remove only the last `/` onwards.  For example: if path is `a//b//c///d`, it would give us `a//b//c//`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where do you find a path like  `a//b//c///d`? The only thing I've run across close to that is converting windows path components with `drive:\\a\\b\\c\\file.ext` to POSIX `drive:/a/b/c/file.ext`. Where can you create a path like `a//b//c///d`? windoze? Or, is this just a generic *strip multiple `'//'`* exercise?

Comment: I am trying to mimic the dirname command.

Comment: `$ dirname "//a///b////c/d//e.txt"` yields `"//a///b////c/d"`. Where does the stripping multiple slashes come from? (or am I just so thick I'm still missing it?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - you are right.  The `dirname` command doesn't strip those slashes.  Not sure why I thought so.

Comment: Similar question: [How to replace multiple spaces with a single space in a string with only bash built-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50259869/6862601).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `extglob` is on:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

you can do this:

```
printf '%s\n' "${path//\/+(\/)/\/}"
```

This uses the `${var//pattern/replacement}` syntax to do a global substitution.

The pattern is `\/+(\/)` (with escaped slashes because `/` is the delimiter), which is really `/+(/)` (where `+(/)` means "one or more slashes").