# How to replace multiple spaces with a single space using Bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, replace

I'd like to use bash to replace multiple adjacent spaces in a string by a single space. Example:

Original string:

```
"too         many       spaces."
```

Transformed string:

```
"too many spaces."
```

I've tried things like `"${str//*( )/.}"` or `awk '{gsub(/[:blank:]/," ")}1'` but I can't get it right.

**Note**: I was able to make it work with `<CMD_THAT_GENERATES_THE_INPUT_STRINGH> | perl -lpe's/\s+/ /g'` but I had to use perl to do the job. I'd like to use **some bash internal syntax** instead of calling an external program, if that is possible.

Comment: OP is probably looking for a bash way not necessarily asking for a `sed` or any other external tool solution.

Comment: Just with built-ins, `str="too         many       spaces.";shopt -s extglob; printf '%s\n' "${str//+([[:space:]])/ }"`

Comment: Re: the `echo $string | perl` note: When IFS is at its default value, `echo $string` *itself* will replace runs of multiple spaces with a single space (along with other side effects, like replacing a wildcard in that string with a list of files) -- one needs to use `echo "$string"` to keep them in. (Even then, `echo` can still munge contents rather than emitting them exactly as they exist; `printf '%s\n' "$string"` is much more reliable).

Comment: @Inian, why not tag this as `string` `replace`?

Comment: @codeforester: _Why_ have them? :) those tags are independent of the programming language used. Not adding any value as such

Comment: @Inian: Even if those tags are independent of the programming language used, keeping them in question will only increase visibility of this question in search results.

Comment: @anubhava: Not sure about it, but added them back though

Comment: How many people will have "string" or "replace" in their tags-to-watch list? Color me in the skeptic camp re: those tags having any value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you may be right: [Do tags help in Google searches?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367648/6862601)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thank you for pointing out that echo already replaces the spaces! I edited my question to show that I wasn't using echo in my tests. I was using <SOME_COMMAND> | perl .... And I wanted to substitute the spaces in the output from SOME_COMMAND

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extra spaces in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092360/608639)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using `tr`:

```
$ echo "too         many       spaces." | tr -s ' '
too many spaces
```

`man tr`:

```
-s, --squeeze-repeats
       replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed  in
       the last specified SET, with a single occurrence of that charac‐
       ter
```

**Edit:** Oh, by the way:

```
$ s="foo      bar"
$ echo $s
foo bar
$ echo "$s"
foo      bar
```

**Edit 2**: On the performance:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ s=$(for i in {1..100} ; do echo -n "word   " ; done) # 100 times: word   word   word...
$ time echo "${s//+([[:blank:]])/ }" > /dev/null

real    0m7.296s
user    0m7.292s
sys     0m0.000s
$ time echo "$s" | tr -s ' ' >/dev/null

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Over 7 seconds?! How is that even possible. Well, this mini laptop is from 2014 but still. Then again:

```
$ time echo "${s//+( )/ }" > /dev/null

real    0m1.198s
user    0m1.192s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: I'd certainly go this route on a POSIX shell where bash extensions weren't available. That said, it's going to be much slower to run (with reasonable input sizes) than the approach given by @anubhava when one *can* use bash.

Comment: Added a test with a hundred words and 3 spaces between each.

Comment: Over 7 seconds every time. `echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.12(1)-release`

Comment: ...waitaminute, found it -- I didn't have extglob enabled. Okay, that's a legitimate result. Might add `shopt -s extglob` to make it copy-and-pasteable for folks trying to repro.

Comment: Upvoted for the benchmarking and showing that an external command is faster than bash itself.!!!

Answer (score 14):

Here is a way to do this using pure `bash` and `extglob`:

```
s="too         many       spaces."

shopt -s extglob
echo "${s//+([[:blank:]])/ }"
```

```
too many spaces.
```

- Bracket expression `[[:blank:]]` matches a space or tab character
- `+([[:blank:]])` matches one or more of the bracket expression (requires `extglob`)

Answer (score 5):

Another simple `sed` expression using BRE is:

```
sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g'
```

For example:

```
$ echo "too         many       spaces." | sed 's/[ ][ ]*/ /g'
too many spaces.
```

There are a number of ways to skin the cat.

If the enclosed *whitespace* could consist of mixed `spaces` and `tabs`, then you could use:

```
sed 's/\s\s*/ /g'
```

And if you simply want to have bash word-splitting handle it, just echo your string without quotes, e.g.

```
$ echo "too         many       spaces." | while read line; do echo $line; done
too many spaces.
```

Continuing with that same thought, if your string with spaces is already stored in a variable, you can simply use `echo` unquoted within *command substitution* to have bash remove the additional whitespace for your, e.g.

```
$ foo="too         many       spaces."; bar=$(echo $foo); echo "$bar"
too many spaces.
```