# How to use cut a string including whitespace

Tags: bash

I'm working on a little Bash script where I need to cut a line into several variables.

Here's an example of the line to cut:

```
00577APP01     REC1_005 R_ESP01_R_TPP2SJAPPCB1
```

I've written this for now:

```
CDSOC=$(echo "${line}" | cut -c1-5)
CDAPP=$(echo "${line}" | cut -c6-15)
IDEXT=$(echo "${line}" | cut -c16-)
```

However, as you can see, the IDEXT in our example is:

```
REC1_005 R_ESP01_R_TPP2SJAPPCB1
```

I'd like to get it back in one piece, but the cut stops at the white space and doesn't continue.

What can I do so that it takes it all?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, the cut doesn't "stop at the white space". What makes you think that? I'd assume you're doing something afterwards that makes bash split at the whitespace.

Comment: When I run your code, I do get _REC1_005 R_ESP01_R_TPP2SJAPPCB1_, so what are you missing? Of course creating 6 child processes just to split a string at certain positions is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: You showed us part of the output you do NOT want, but you haven't told us why that's unexpected nor shown us the output you DO want yet so we'd just be guessing at how to help you get whatever it is you expect. Please [edit] your question to show the expected output, i.e. the values of those 3 variables you're trying to populate. Regarding "I'd like to get it back in one piece" - you'd like to get WHAT back in one piece? Regarding "but the cut stops at the white space and doesn't continue" - no, it doesn't, please tells us why you think that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to [replace multiple spaces with a single space using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259880/6771046) before. In order to translate or delete characters you could use [`tr` --squeeze-repeats](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html)

> "*replace each sequence of a repeated character that is listed in the last specified ARRAY, with a single occurrence of that character*"

```
tr -s ' '
```

Then, further processing can be done on [`--fieds | -f`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

> "*select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified*"

```bash
echo "00577APP01     REC1_005 R_ESP01_R_TPP2SJAPPCB1" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
REC1_005 R_ESP01_R_TPP2SJAPPCB1
```

Answer (score 0):

The cut command in BASH can be used to extract a substring from a string using a delimiter. To use space as a delimiter, you can use the -d option followed by a single quote containing a space. For example, cut -d ' ' -f 2 will extract the second field from a space-delimited string

However, the cut command does not treat multiple spaces as one delimiter, so if your string has variable number of spaces between fields, you may get unexpected results. In that case, you can use other commands such as sed, awk, tr, or xargs to trim the whitespaces before or after using cut.

Here is an example of using xargs to trim the whitespaces and then cut to extract the third field:

echo "  BASH   is   fun  " | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f 3

This will output fun